# implicit conversion NSNumber* to int

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have two view controllers  VC1 and VC2. VC1 has a textField and button. the VC2 has a property of type NSNumber* .

I am trying to pass the value in the textfield in VC1 to VC2, so I did the following in VC1

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SEGUE_IFENTIFIER_TO_DETAILS_VIEW_CONTROLLER]) {

    ((DetailsViewController *)  
    segue.destinationViewController).receivedData =
    self.textFieldValueToDispatch.text.intValue;
}
```

but I receive an error saying : `implicit conversion on int_nullable`

how to solve it

Comment: Change this segue.destinationViewController).receivedData =
    self.textFieldValueToDispatch.text.intValue; to segue.destinationViewController).receivedData =
    [self.textFieldValueToDispatch.text intValue];
And ensure your receivedData is int type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Converting NSString to Int**

```
int value = [@"1234" integerValue]; // Int Type
```

**Converting Int to NSNumber**

```
// Using NSNumber methods
NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1234]; 

// Using NSNumber literals
NSNumber * number = @(1234);
```

**Converting String to NSNumber**

```
// Using NSNumber methods
NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[@"" integerValue]];

// Using NSNumber literals
NSNumber * number = @([@"" integerValue]);
```

**Your Solution**

```
((DetailsViewController *) segue.destinationViewController).receivedData =
@([self.textFieldValueToDispatch.text integerValue]);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but it would help others if you edit your answer and  explain what the `@( ... )` is doing.

Answer (score 2):

- `NSNumber` is an object
- `int` / `NSInteger` is a primitive scalar type

Both types are not interchangeable.

The easiest solution is to create an `NSNumber` object from `NSInteger`with ObjC literal

```
((DetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).receivedData =
                         @(self.textFieldValueToDispatch.text.integerValue);
```

`@(123)` is the same as `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:123]`

Comment: received data is of type NSNumber*, and  I used your solution, and it does not work

Comment: What does not work? Compile error? Runtime error? What error? Of course the conversion works only if the text field contains a numeric value.